# Легкий скрипт который копирует файлы с сегодняшним днем

Tags: bash, shell, автоматизация

мне нужна ваша помощь в создании скрипта:
каждый день учитель загружает файлы в следуюещем формате:

```
ACCOUNTS_STUDENT_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx  
STUDENT_MARKS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx  
STUNDENT_HOMEWORKS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx  
STUDENT_PHYSICAL_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx  
STUDENTS_SUBSCRIBED_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx
```

**[file_name+todaydatetime-todaydate.xlsx]**

Но иногда учитель не загружает эти файлы и мне надо вручную переименовывать файлы которые были загружены вчера и копировать их каждый в отдельную папку:

```
cp ACCOUNTS_STUDENT_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx /incoming/A1/ACCOUNTS_STUDENT_20200318074343-20200318.xlsx  
cp MARKS_STUDENT_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx  /incoming/B1/ACCOUNTS_STUDENT_20200318074343-20200318.xlsx  
.............

cp SUBSCRIBED_STUDENTS_20200217074343-20200217.xlsx /incoming/F1/SUBSCRIBED_STUDENTS_20200318074343-20200318.xlsx.
```

В двух словах - беру файлы за предыдущий день копирую их в специальную папку с новой временной меткой:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/incoming/
date=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
previousdate=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
cp /home/incoming/STUDENTS_SUBSCRIBED_'$previousdate'.xlsx /incoming/F1/STUDENTS_SUBSCRIBED_'$date'.xlsx
```

иногда также учитель загружает один файл, а остальные отсуствуют и нужно скопировать и переименовать файлы за предыдущий день, как сделать проверку на имеющиеся файлы?
Спасибо за то что прочли, вы мне очень поможете если укажите как это сдлетаь правильно.

Comment: Если вам просто нужно проверить существование файла, то это [`test -e`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Comment: а если каждый день файл имеет новую временную метку? как с тестом это сделать?

Comment: Простите, но я так и не смог распарсить, в чём именно задача.  Либо подождите комментариев и ответов от других, либо напишите псевдокодом хотя бы, что вам нужно.

Comment: попробую попроще расписать,за помощь готов вам готов отправить деньги пейпелом

Comment: Я конечно понимаю, что у вас на аватарке Билл Гейтс, но вообще на СО деньги за ответы, и уж тем более за комментарии, давать не принято :-P  Если вам их некуда девать, рекомендую найти благотворительный фонд.

Comment: попробую попроще расписать,за помощь готов вам готов отправить деньги пейпелом: каждый день учитель загружаеткаждый день список файлов ( их 45 они имеют определенное имя вроде того же STUDENT_SUBSCRIBED_ДАТА  и тд,) иногда учитель загружает от одного до 30 файлов  - из 45 и нужно недостающие файлы скопирывать с предыдущего дня) все файлы он заливает в /incoming/ а оттуда я вручную перемещаю в /incoming/data-2020318/.  Есть ли возможнсоть это сдлеать? З.Ы. Да на пиво тоже самое и ваше время :)

Comment: `cd $NEXT_DATE_FOLDER; find $PREVIOUS_DATE_FOLDER -type f -name "*.xlsx" | while read fprev; do ...convert to new name in some new variable, let's say fnext...; [ -s "$fnext" ] || cp "$PREVIOUS_DATE_FOLDER/fprev" "$fnext"; done`. Поддержки пробелов и специальных символов добавить по вкусу. Работы, даже не зная shell, на часа два-три с помощью того же SO.

Comment: @0andriy, оформи как ответ, а то глаза слезятся.